# How to use Rails partial counter variable when passing a single object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller I have one single collection which consists of two objects, folders and images. In my view I'm trying to pass the whole collection into a partial and then separate them out based on their object type. For example I have this call

```
 <%= render :partial => 'layouts/merged_element', :collection => @merged_collection, as: :merged_element, locals: {folder_count: @total_folders_count, image_count: @total_images_count} %>
```

and then inside the layouts/merged_element partial I have another call which separates them out.

```
<% if merged_element.instance_of?(Folder) %>
   <%= render :partial => 'layouts/folder', :object => merged_element, as: 'folder', :locals => { :show_bottom_border => true, :total_folder_count => folder_count, :total_image_count => image_count} %>
<% elsif merged_element.instance_of?(Image) %>
   <%= render :partial => 'layouts/image', :object => merged_element, as: 'image',  :locals => { :show_bottom_border => false, :total_folder_count => folder_count, :total_image_count => image_count } %>
```

Now I would like to find a way to have access to each partials local counter variable. Something like a folder_counter and image_counter variable for each. But I see that Rails only provides the counter variable for collections once and not single objects. Is there a way in which I can get to the counter variables of both partials??